# $\frac{1}{x}$ is Bounded Variation or NOT

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a little confusion about this example of bounded variation :

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ in the interval $(0,1)$.

As the function $f$ is monotone decreasing in $(0,1)$ so it is Bounded Variation.

Again the function is NOT bounded in $(0,1)$. So it is NOT of Bounded Variation.

So what I conclude about $f$ ?

Comment: Re-check your notes. Monotonicity implies bounded variation _on compact intervals_, not on arbitrary intervals.

Comment: What can you say when $f(x)= \tan(x)$ on $[0,pi /2]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bounded monotone function is BV. An unbounded function is never BV. You get boundedness for free from monotonicity if the domain is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the function $f(x)=\frac1x$ is not bounded variation on $(0,1)$ because it doesn't play nicely in the domain. The amount that it moves on the y axis over this domain is infinite.

For a real-valued continuous function f, defined on an interval [a, b] ⊂ ℝ, its total variation on the interval of definition is a measure of the one-dimensional arclength of the curve with parametric equation x ↦ f(x), for x ∈ [a, b].

(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation)

---

A function with bounded variation has finite total variation.

(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation)